# Assigning MS Graph API permissions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to interrogate the calendar for the logged in user.  I can do this using the Graph Explorer fine, but when I try this in code I get an access denied exception.  I'm trying to create a system, whereby a user can log-in and then add entries to their calendar, so I assumed a possible way forward would be to programmatically assign permissions; however, this also gives me an error that I don't have permissions.  Is someone able to point me in the right direction here; I realise that I can simply allow permission against my own profile, but I need this to be something that any user can simply consent to.

Here's the code that I have to assign permissions:

```
var requestBody = new CalendarPermission
{
    Role = CalendarRoleType.Read
};

var calendarPermissions = await graphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();

var result = await graphClient.Users[userId]
    .Calendar.CalendarPermissions["798ee544-9d2d-430c-a058-570e29e34338"]
    .PatchAsync(requestBody);
```

And here is the code where I try to interrogate the calendar:

```
var result = await graphClient.Me.Events.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "subject", "organizer", "start", "end" };
});
```

Both return access denied.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly about using `graphClient.Users[userId]
    .Calendar.CalendarPermissions`. What I can say is, calling this API is not used for solving your `access denied exception`. Here's the API document for explaining when to use this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assumed a possible way forward would be to programmatically assign
> permissions; however, this also gives me an error that I don't have
> permissions

Hi, when we want to use graph api, we need to register an Azure AD application in Azure portal, and add required API permissions. Some API permissions are also requiring admin consent.

In your scenario, you have now having [Calendar permission update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendarpermission-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) and [event list api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), which both require `Calendars.ReadBasic, Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite` api permissions. And like we can see, the permissions are not requiring admin consent.

[image]

Therefore, before we calling these 2 APIs, we'd better to add API permissions in advance. Just like what we did when testing in Graph Explorer.

[image]

After adding the API permission, then when you run your app and a user sign in with his account, he would have a popup which indicating a consent is required for using this app.

[image]

And by my test, even if I didn't add the api permission, I can also add api permission in code to do it.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read", "Calendars.ReadWrite" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense - thankyou.  However, "Therefore, before we calling these 2 APIs, we'd better to add API permissions in advance. Just like what we did when testing in Graph Explorer." - where are these permissions added?

Comment: open azure portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> App registrations blade -> choose the azure ad application you created for your code -> API permissions blade -> click add api permission option, then choose microsoft graph api. you can see my screenshot in the post.

Comment: @sid I trust you already had an Azure AD application, otherwise you aren't able to integrate authentication into your project.

Comment: As it stands I'm still experimenting with a console app.  I can create an app registration, although I'm interested in how this would work if I didn't want to use Azure for my app

Comment: @sid  Hi , graph api can work in 2 modes, one is call graph API on behalf of a specific user which requires `delegated` API permission type, then it requires a users to sign in first so that the API could work which is not suitable for a console app. Another is calling Graph Api on behalf of the application itself, it doesn' require a user to sign in so that it is suitable for a console application, but it needs `Application` type of API permission. Using application api permisson doesn't allow to call api on behalf of any specific user, but it could get  any users' information in your tenant.

Comment: by the way, both of them need an Azure AD application